# Using react-router-dom v6.8.2 in react class based component Link doesn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am learning react js and creating a news app using newsapi in a React class component. I have installed `react-router-dom@6.8.2` in my appilcation. I don't know what I did wrong but in my application `Link` is not working and my url did change but I don't not get desire output according to `category`.

file structure:

[image]

Here is my index.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

file : App.js

```
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import News from "./components/News";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={<News pageSize={5} country="in" category="general" />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/business"
            element={<News pageSize={5} country="in" category="business" />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/entertainment"
            element={<News pageSize={5} country="in" category="entertainment" />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/health"
            element={<News pageSize={5} country="in" category="health" />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/science"
            element={<News pageSize={5} country="in" category="science" />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/sports"
            element={<News pageSize={5} country="in" category="sports" />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/technology"
            element={<News pageSize={5} country="in" category="technology" />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

file:  NavBar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav
          className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary"
          data-bs-theme="light"
        >
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <img src="WHHlogo.png" className="Web-logo" alt="logo" />
            <button
              className="navbar-toggler"
              type="button"
              data-bs-toggle="collapse"
              data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-expanded="false"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
              <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div
              className="collapse navbar-collapse" 
              id="navbarSupportedContent"
            >
              <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 mx-3">
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link className="nav-link" aria-current="page" to="/">
                    Home
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to="/business">
                    Business
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to="/entertainment">
                    Entertainment
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to="/health">
                    Health
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to="/science">
                    Science
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to="/sports">
                    Sports
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to="/technology">
                    Technology
                  </Link>
                </li>                     
              </ul>
              <div className="d-flex form-check form-switch">
                <input
                  className="form-check-input"
                  type="checkbox"
                  role="switch"
                  id="flexSwitchCheckDefault"
                />
                <label
                  className="form-check-label" 
                  htmlFor="flexSwitchCheckDefault"
                >
                  Dark Mode
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

file: News.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import NewsItem from './NewsItem'
import Spinner from './Spinner';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'


export default class News extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    country:'in',
    pageSize:8,
    category:'general'
  }
  static propTypes = {
    country: PropTypes.string,
    pageSize:PropTypes.number,
    category:PropTypes.string,
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      articles: [],
      loading: false,
      page: 1,
    }
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=**writeyourapikey**&page=1&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
    this.setState({
      loading:true
    });
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parseData = await data.json();
    this.setState({ articles: parseData.articles })
    console.log(parseData);
    this.setState({
      articles: parseData.articles,
      totalResults: parseData.totalResults,
      loading:false
    })
  }
  handleNextClick = async () => {
    console.log("next")
    let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&apiKey=**writeyourapikey**&page=${this.state.page + 1}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
    this.setState({
      loading:true
    });
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parseData = await data.json();
    console.log(parseData);

    this.setState({
      page: this.state.page + 1,
      articles: parseData.articles,
      loading:false
    })
  }
  handlePreClick = async () => {
    console.log("previous")

    let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&apiKey=**writeyourapikey**&page=${this.state.page - 1}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
    this.setState({
      loading:true
    });
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parseData = await data.json();
    console.log(parseData);

    this.setState({
      page: this.state.page - 1,
      articles: parseData.articles,
      loading:false
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container my-3'>
        <h2 className="text-center">HeadlineHunter - Top Breaking News</h2>
        {this.state.loading && <Spinner/>}
        <div className="row">
          {!this.state.loading && this.state.articles.map((element) => (
            <div className="col-md-4" key={element.url}>
              <NewsItem title={element.title ? element.title : ""} description={element.description ? element.description : element.title} imgUrl={element.urlToImage} newsUrl={element.url} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>

        <div className="container d-flex justify-content-between ">
          <button disabled={this.state.page <= 1} className="btn btn-dark" onClick={this.handlePreClick} type="button">&larr; Previous</button>
          <button disabled={this.state.articles.length ===0} className="btn btn-dark" onClick={this.handleNextClick} type="button">Next &rarr;</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I am expecting to get the articles according to category wise

Comment: Is there any error in your browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-router-dom` optimizes the rendered route components so they remain mounted when only the path they are rendered on updates. This means you should also implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method to handle when props update.

I suggest abstracting the fetching logic from `componentDidMount` into a utility function that is called in both lifecycle methods. Then the `category` or `country` props update/change then refetch the appropriate data.

Example:

```
export default class News extends Component {
  ...

  fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=**witeyourapikey**&page=1&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;

      this.setState({ loading: true });

      const data = await fetch(url);
      const parseData = await data.json();
    
      console.log(parseData);
      this.setState({
        articles: parseData.articles,
        totalResults: parseData.totalResults
      });
    } catch {
      // catch/handle any errors
    } finally {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (
      prevProps.country !== this.props.country ||
      prevProps.category !== this.props.category ||
      prevProps.pageSize !== this.props.pageSize
    ) {
      this.fetchData();
    }
  }

  ...

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```